# Incremental generation with Acceleo 3

Tags: acceleo

I wanted to do some incremental generation with Acceleo 3. Typically generate some code, write some specific functions, and when I regenerate I don't want to override the code I wrote.

I know it's possible in Acceleo 2.8 (http://www.acceleo.org/pages/incremental-generation/en) but I don't see any example of that in Acceleo 3 documentation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Acceleo 3 features the same mechanism as Acceleo 2 to protect some piece of user code. You can use a protected area defined in the generator to let your user change the code as they want in the protected area or if you are generating Java, you can also use JMerge to protected a documented element (@generated NOT in the documentation of a Java element to protected it). You can watch those two behaviors in video in the [documentation](http://www.obeonetwork.com/page/working-with-an-existing) of Acceleo 3.1
You can also have a look at the best practices guide and all the other features of Acceleo 3.1 in the [user guide](http://www.obeonetwork.com/acceleo).

Stephane Begaudeau